# Notification throttling has bad behaviour

Tags: fiware-orion

I have deployed a empty Orion and connected a device that sends updates ervery 10 secs. I need to receive one notification each 10 min so I have created a notification with a throttling of 600 s.

The problem is that I am reciving two notifications in the same minute or even a couple seconds after the first one.

1) One instance of orion version: 2.2.0

2) Orion suscriptions

```
[
    {
        "id": "5e9ec90d9e2ba22996168d78",
        "description": "Notificaciones a Arcgis",
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "status": "active",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "id1",
                    "type": "aqss"
                }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": []
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "timesSent": 521026,
            "lastNotification": "2020-05-21T10:52:53.00Z",
            "attrs": [],
            "attrsFormat": "normalized",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://test.eu/notify/"
            },
            "metadata": [
                "dateCreated",
                "dateModified"
            ],
            "lastFailure": "2020-05-20T16:46:58.00Z",
            "lastFailureReason": "Timeout was reached",
            "lastSuccess": "2020-05-21T10:52:53.00Z",
            "lastSuccessCode": 500
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5e9ec96f9e2ba22996168d79",
        "description": "Notificaciones a Arcgis",
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "status": "active",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "id2",
                    "type": "aqss"
                }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": []
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "timesSent": 526757,
            "lastNotification": "2020-05-21T10:52:50.00Z",
            "attrs": [],
            "attrsFormat": "normalized",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://test.eu/notify/"
            },
            "metadata": [
                "dateCreated",
                "dateModified"
            ],
            "lastFailure": "2020-05-21T09:32:34.00Z",
            "lastFailureReason": "Timeout was reached",
            "lastSuccess": "2020-05-21T10:52:50.00Z",
            "lastSuccessCode": 500
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5e9ec9899e2ba22996168d7a",
        "description": "Notificaciones a Arcgis",
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "status": "active",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "id3",
                    "type": "aqss"
                }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": []
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "timesSent": 541814,
            "lastNotification": "2020-05-21T10:52:47.00Z",
            "attrs": [],
            "attrsFormat": "normalized",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://test.eu/notify/"
            },
            "metadata": [
                "dateCreated",
                "dateModified"
            ],
            "lastFailure": "2020-05-21T01:49:52.00Z",
            "lastFailureReason": "Timeout was reached",
            "lastSuccess": "2020-05-21T10:52:48.00Z",
            "lastSuccessCode": 500
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5e9ec9a69e2ba22996168d7b",
        "description": "Notificaciones a Arcgis",
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "status": "active",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "id3",
                    "type": "aqss"
                }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": []
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "timesSent": 470859,
            "lastNotification": "2020-05-21T10:52:47.00Z",
            "attrs": [],
            "attrsFormat": "normalized",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://test.eu/notify/"
            },
            "metadata": [
                "dateCreated",
                "dateModified"
            ],
            "lastFailure": "2020-05-20T21:01:32.00Z",
            "lastFailureReason": "Timeout was reached",
            "lastSuccess": "2020-05-21T10:52:47.00Z",
            "lastSuccessCode": 500
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5e9ec9c09e2ba22996168d7c",
        "description": "Notificaciones a Arcgis",
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "status": "active",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "id4",
                    "type": "aqss"
                }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": []
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "timesSent": 532901,
            "lastNotification": "2020-05-21T10:52:44.00Z",
            "attrs": [],
            "attrsFormat": "normalized",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://test.eu/notify/"
            },
            "metadata": [
                "dateCreated",
                "dateModified"
            ],
            "lastFailure": "2020-05-21T08:33:10.00Z",
            "lastFailureReason": "Timeout was reached",
            "lastSuccess": "2020-05-21T10:52:45.00Z",
            "lastSuccessCode": 500
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5e9ec9ff9e2ba22996168d7d",
        "description": "Notificaciones a Arcgis",
        "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
        "status": "active",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "id5",
                    "type": "aqss"
                }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": []
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "timesSent": 520974,
            "lastNotification": "2020-05-21T10:52:53.00Z",
            "attrs": [],
            "attrsFormat": "normalized",
            "http": {
                "url": "http://test.eu/notify/"
            },
            "metadata": [
                "dateCreated",
                "dateModified"
            ],
            "lastFailure": "2020-05-21T05:30:58.00Z",
            "lastFailureReason": "Timeout was reached",
            "lastSuccess": "2020-05-21T10:52:53.00Z",
            "lastSuccessCode": 500
        }
    }
]
```

3) Orion is running in a docker instance

```
[root@271386b095c6 /]# ps ax
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ssl  320:12 /usr/bin/contextBroker -fg -multiservice -ngsiv1Autocast -dbhost mongo -corsOrigin __ALL -logLevel DEBUG
 9248 pts/0    Ss     0:00 bash
 9293 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps ax
```

4) Pending...

5) Entities and suscriptions belong to the same service and service-path

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I have some questions, to clarify the setup: 1) How many Orion instances are you running? 2) How many subscriptions do you have (`GET /v2/subscriptions` would provide that information)? 3) How do your run Orion (`ps ax | grep contextBroker` would provide that)? 4) How is the payload of the notifications that are received almost at the same time? Please edit your question post to include the answer for all them. Thanks!

Comment: And 5) :), do the subscriptions and the entities belong to the same service and subservice (I mean, all the involved requests are using same `fiware-service` and `fiware-servicepath` headers)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the info above, it seems you have a lot of subscriptions. Six of them, if I have counted correctly.

Not sure if all of them are covering the same entities/attributes, but my recommendation would be to simplify your scenario leaving *only one subscription* and test again.

You can delete subscription using `DELETE /v2/subscriptions/{subId}`.